# Selenium Deprecated elements

Tags: selenium

This is my code.
I'm trying to get selenium to print the price of an item from a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_driver_path = Service('C:/Development/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Multi-Use-Programmable-Pressure/dp/B00FLYWNYQ')

price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-offscreen')
print(price)


driver.quit()
```

**I'm receiving an error:**

```
Start/main.py:9: **DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_ commands are deprecated. Please use find_element()instead**
  price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-offscreen')
```